# Would Utilizing an Instance Variable in a Processor Class Potentially Cause a Race Condition?

Tags: java

I am initializing an instance variable simply to null, and setting it inside a subsequent method in a processor class. If a transaction runs with a cache of processors would this potentially cause a race condition?

The code is something like

```
 Object customObject = null;

 @Override
 public void initialize(anotherCustomerObj anotherCustom) throws Exception{
 customObject = anotherCustom.getCustomObject();

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Imagine you have two threads

Thread 1

```
thing.initialize(foo);  // Operation 1
thing.doSomething();    // Operation 2
```

Thread 2

```
thing.intialize(bar);   // Operation 3
thing.doSomething();    // Operation 4
```

Imagine the scheduler schedules these operations in this order: 1, 3, 2, 4

Operation 2 will operate upon either `foo` or `bar` (the field is not volatile, so visibility of the update is not guaranteed).